# Index Error appears after a certain number of loops (python)

Tags: python

I've created a list within a list from a file and the format basically is List= [[a,b,c][d,e,f][g,h,i].....], i want to access always the second element of each list (b,e,h...) and with the code below it works up until 83 whereas the length of the list is 255, after those 83 elements python tells me that the Index is out of range, i've also tried to replace len(list) with 255 just to see where the problem lies but the same happens. Does anyone know what the problem is ?

`x = 0
while x < len(List):
    print(List[x][1])
    x += 1`

Comment: If you print `List[84]` you will probably find that it has fewer than two elements.

Comment: thanks that's actually the problem.. i just didn't think of it because the list i've created is from a file which is supplied by our lecturers so i didn't think the problem would be in there but as it turns out the file is wrong exactly at this point.....

Answer (score 0):

- The below code should solve you problem

  ```
  x = 0
  while x < len(List):
      if len(List[x]) > 2:
          print(List[x][1])
      x += 1
  ```
- I think the `List[x]` does not has elements inside so you are getting index error

Comment: Why not `if len(List[x]) > 1:` ? If you run your code with `["y", "z"]` in the array, "z" will be left out.

Comment: @gil.fernandes See the question what he's trying to print... I am assuming his data structure is list of list [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]... And he's trying to print the element at index 1 for every iner list

Answer (score 0):

Always use for loop when there are fixed known no: of iterations. Use while when the iterations are unknown like the no: of iterations are calculated from the program dynamically(for example finding Armstrong no:).

```
#check syntax for python if version 3 above, i use 2.7
    for i in List:         #taking each list out of List as i
        if len(i)>=2:      #to retrieve second element the list should have 
            print(i[1])    #atleast 2 elements
```

Comment: Did this work, any improvement in result? can you give your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are accessing arrays which do not contain a second element, because the length of the array is less than 2.

Apart from that your code could be simplified by omitting the `x` variable. You can use a plain `for` in order to iterate through the list.

I suggest some code along these lines:

```
List = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"], [], ["z"], ["y", "z"]]
for array in List:
    if(len(array) > 1):
        print(array[1])
```

If you run this code it will print out the second element of the sub-list, in case it exists, like e.g:

```
b
e
h
z
```

Answer (score -1):

I expect there may be one of your inner lists that only has one element. You should also use a `for` loop:

```
for element in List:
    print(element[1])
```

If one of your inner lists is too short, it's probably an error, and rather than checking its length (`if len(element) > 2`), this becomes more clear if you use exception handling:

```
for element in List:
    try:
        print(element[1])
    except IndexError as e:
        print(f'list has too few elements: {element}')
```

Comment: If one of the *inner* lists only has one item, this will produce the same result the OP is asking about.

Comment: That's the word I was looking for. Thanks. I also very clearly did not specify that this was a solution to his data problem. Since he has wrong assumptions about his data, perhaps that issue is better solved elsewhere. I'll add some error handling nonetheless.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, since SO isn't a discussion forum answers are supposed solve the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: At the same time, there are a lot of learners who don't know enough to ask the right sort of question, and they should be nudged in the right direction. But this is itself turning into a discussion, so I'll leave it at this.